# Tuition Increase

Tags: c#

I am trying to get this to display Year 1 `original tuition + interest rate` then have all the interest rates compound afterwards. It gets stuck on Year 2 then just repeats.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double originalTuition = 6000.00;
    double newTuition;
    double interestRate = 0.02;
    tuitionListBox.Items.Clear();

    for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
    {
        if (year == 1)
            newTuition = originalTuition;

        else
            newTuition = originalTuition + (originalTuition * interestRate);
            newTuition = newTuition + (newTuition * interestRate);
            tuitionListBox.Items.Add(year + "\t" + newTuition.ToString("c"));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the proper location to put a question like this in as there is no specific error you are receiving.  This is a more of a logic question.

Comment: with my above comment being said.  IMHO you should wrap your if/else with the proper brackets and look at the use of += in your code block.  I'm not sure what is going on at the end of your for loop either, so you would have to include that in your code.

Comment: Indentation can make your code more readable. But braces `{` and `}` are very important to having your code compile and execute the way you want. Can you please include enough code so that your function and your `for` loop can compile. In general, you are much less likely to have bugs crop up if you but braces around even single statement blocks in constructs like `if` statements.

Comment: You haven't closed your for loop. If all you have left in the code is a curly bracket '}', please include it. There are a few different problems with your code but we need to start with a complete method before I can fix all of them.

Comment: Always format your code properly, when you do, the error reveals itself to you a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

newTuition will always start with the same value after year 1 due to your ‘else’ block.  My guess is you want to remove the first line of code after the ‘else’.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize **newTuition** variable.
Then below code:

```
for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
{
    if (year == 1)
        newTuition = originalTuition;
    else
        newTuition = newTuition + (newTuition * interestRate);
   tuitionListBox.Items.Add(year + "\t" + newTuition.ToString("c"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new method for clarity and reusability. Using brackets with if/else statements makes the code more easy to read, and thereby identifying the problem.

```
private List<double> GetAnnualTuitions(double originalTuition, double interestRate, int numOfYears)
    {
        double newTuition = 0;
        List<double> tuitions = new List<double>();
        for (int year = 1; year <= numOfYears; year++)
        {
            if (year == 1)
            {
                newTuition = originalTuition;
            }
            else
            {
                newTuition += (newTuition * interestRate);
            }
            tuitions.Add(newTuition);
        }
        return tuitions;
    }
```